# How to maximize a linear combination with respect to ORDER

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, vector-spaces

I have a set of values $p_i$ (probability), each associates itself to a $s_i$ (string length), with $1 \le i \le n$. I want to maximize the value of a certain linear combination **with respect to their order**.

Let me elaborate with an example. Lets say I'm given the set $\{(p_x, s_x),(p_y, s_y),(p_z,s_z)\}$. I want to consider how to **order** them so that the linear combination of

$$ (0,0,0)\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
p_z\\
p_y\\
p_x\\
\end{array}
\right) + (0,0,s_y)\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
p_z\\
p_y\\
p_x\\
\end{array}
\right) + (0,s_z,s_z)\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
p_z\\
p_y\\
p_x\\
\end{array}
\right)$$ is maximized.

i.e. I want to compare the above order to

$$ (0,0,0)\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
p_x\\
p_y\\
p_z\\
\end{array}
\right) + (0,0,s_y)\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
p_x\\
p_y\\
p_z\\
\end{array}
\right) + (0,s_x,s_x)\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
p_x\\
p_y\\
p_z\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Or:

$$ (0,0,0)\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
p_y\\
p_z\\
p_x\\
\end{array}
\right) + (0,0,s_z)\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
p_y\\
p_z\\
p_x\\
\end{array}
\right) + (0,s_y,s_y)\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
p_y\\
p_z\\
p_x\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

And so on, to see which one yields the maximum result.

How can I do that without manually comparing them one by one?

Comment: Whats the point of multiplying by (0,0,0)?

Comment: nothing, I just put it there for formalities b/c of the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Your problem statement still needs some clearance. What do you call an order? How many combinations exist?

Comment: I don't want to over complicate the problem by defining too many definitions. The order is just like the examples provided, by switching the elements of the P column vectors around and also replacing the row vectors in the same order. The number of combinations that exists is obvious a permutation of the number of elements in the set. So in the example given, 6